# Adapting argument list in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to implement the `unapply` method but, I get the following strange error:

```
Adapting argument list by creating a 4-tuple: this may not be what you want.
[error]         signature: Some.apply[A](x: A): Some[A]
[error]   given arguments: genre._id, genre.name, genre.created, genre.updated
[error]  after adaptation: Some((genre._id, genre.name, genre.created, genre.updated): (Option[reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID], String, Option[org.joda.time.DateTime], Option[org.joda.time.DateTime]))
[error]     Some(genre._id, genre.name, genre.created, genre.updated)
[error]         ^
```

Here's my code:

```
def unapply(genre: Genre): Option[(Option[BSONObjectID], String, 
                                   Option[DateTime], Option[DateTime])] =
    Some(genre._id, genre.name, genre.created, genre.updated)
```

I am doing this as part of the JSON conversion:

```
implicit val genreWrites: OWrites[Genre] = (
    (__ \ "_id").writeNullable[BSONObjectID] and
      (__ \ "name").write[String] and
      (__ \ "created").writeNullable[DateTime] and
      (__ \ "updated").writeNullable[DateTime]
    ) (unlift(Genre.unapply))
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need additional parenthesis to declare the tuple:

```
Some((genre._id, genre.name, genre.created, genre.updated))
```

What the compiler is telling you is that you're passing multiple parameters to `Some[A].apply` which expects a single argument of type `A`.